# OpenCL enqueueWriteImage no const void* ptr in C++ wrapper but in C function

Tags: c++, opencl

In `cl2.hpp` enqueueWriteImage takes a `void* ptr` but calls the C function `clEnqueueWriteImage` which takes a `const void* ptr`. Why is that?

```
cl_int enqueueWriteImage(
    const Image& image,
    cl_bool blocking,
    const array<size_type, 3>& origin,
    const array<size_type, 3>& region,
    size_type row_pitch,
    size_type slice_pitch,
    void* ptr,
    const vector<Event>* events = NULL,
    Event* event = NULL) const
{
    cl_event tmp;
    cl_int err = detail::errHandler(
        ::clEnqueueWriteImage(//... here the const void* ptr appears
```

Is this intended or a typo? Because it is only calling a function that accepts a `const void* ptr` so it could be const, too.

Comment: Looks like a copy paste typo from ReadImage (that has to be non constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; this is a bug in the OpenCL C++ bindings. There were a few other `enqueueWrite*` functions with this same issue. I've pushed a fix to the [Khronos GitHub repository for these headers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP) - it will be included in the next release.